# Is it ok to call several (more than one) async actions on component mount?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, action

Is it ok to dispatch several async actions in `componentDidMount` method? 
Some of them are connected - for example, first I fetch report types that belongs to actual user, then I fetch report details based on report type. Now I want to call another report details action. It would be like:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.reportTypesAction().then(
    () => {
      this.setState({ reportTypes: this.props.reportTypes });
      this.props.reportAction();
      this.propt.anotherReportAction();
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: is it giving you any error or are you just asking if it's okay?

Comment: There is no error, there are no bugs - just asking if it's ok, or maybe I should wait for actions to complete before calling another.

Comment: Yeah, it's ok, I don't see why anything would go wrong

Comment: if none of the async operations are depended on each other then i don't see any problem with this approach.

Comment: @papryk not an issue.But avoid unwanted dispacth and if it possible to merge it multiple dispatch within single dispatch then should do,Otherwise too many re-rendering.

Comment: If one call is dependent on another then you have to wait for action to complete but if they both are independent call i don't see any problem with it. React will handle if you update your state correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to call any number of them in `componentDidMount` if they are supposed to be called then. But handling a promise which is not immediately given to callback but saved to redux store and referenced from props in the promise chain is not optimal.

What I mean is you could dispatch a single `reportTypesAction` synchronously to store and use `redux-saga` to handle the rest of updates dealing with promises easily.

Using a single dispatch approach `this.setState` would be conditionally called in `componentDidUpdate` or `shouldComponentUpdate` since in `componentDidMount`, `this.props.reportTypes` may be empty.

This may also avoid unnecessary re-render.